# Unlock keyring with fingerprint - Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: login, fingerprint-reader, gnome-keyring

Ubuntu 18.10 offers the option to login with fingerprint. However, the login does not unlock the gnome keyring, and therefore after a login via fingerprint I have to type the password on the keyboard.

Is there an option to unlock the keyring at the login with my fingerprint, too? (without installing any ppa - I remember that fingerprint-gui had that capability). Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here with ubuntu 20.04... Did you eventually manage to solve it ?